# show uipickerview after some delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

i have uitextfield and added picker view as input view.

everything work perfect. my problem is once i click on uitextfield picker view appears with values. but i am getting some data from database, which will be updated for another textbox depend on picker value selected.

there is 5-6 sec time interval by the time i get data from DB. but picker view is visible with preloaded values, before calls return back with data.

i just want to add kind of delay till i get data from DB picker value should not be visible...
Note: i already used hidden. does not work properly.

```
UIPickerView  *vwlistPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
[vwlistPicker sizeToFit];
vwlistPicker.delegate = self;
vwlistPicker.dataSource = self;
vwlistPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

UITextField  *txtPayType = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 65, 250, 30)];
txtPayType.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
txtPayType.layer.masksToBounds = true;
txtPayType.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
txtPayType.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
txtPayType.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(5, 0, 0);
txtPayType.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
txtPayType.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
txtPayType.tag = 1;
[txtPayType setDelegate:self];
txtPayType.text = [tempDic valueForKey:@"PayType"];
[txtPayType setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Medium" size:15.0]];
[txtPayType setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:19.0/255.0 green:62.0/255.0 blue:137.0/255.0 alpha:1]];
[txtPayType setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
txtPayType.inputView = vwlistPicker;

UIToolbar* keyboardDoneButtonView = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
keyboardDoneButtonView.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
keyboardDoneButtonView.translucent = NO;
keyboardDoneButtonView.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:10.0/255.0 green:23.0/255.0 blue:75.0/255.0 alpha:0];

[keyboardDoneButtonView sizeToFit];

UIBarButtonItem* doneButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                                style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self
                                                               action:@selector(itemPickerDoneClicked:)] autorelease];

UIBarButtonItem* cancelButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self
                                                                 action:@selector(itemPickerCancelClicked:)] autorelease];


[keyboardDoneButtonView setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:doneButton,cancelButton, nil]];

txtPayType.inputAccessoryView = keyboardDoneButtonView;

[self.view addSubview:txtPayType];

//Textfield delegate

    -(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        if(textField.tag == 1)
        {
            [vwlistPicker setHidden:TRUE];
            double delayInSeconds = 5;
            dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
            dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                [vwlistPicker reloadInputViews];
                textField.inputView = vwlistPicker;
                [vwlistPicker reloadAllComponents];
                [vwlistPicker setHidden:FALSE];
            });
// Call to DB and get Data //
    }
```

i added delay / hidden (keyboard as well as pickerview) but still keyboard appears. and after delays picker view option appear.

i do not want anything to shown and once i get data picker view to appear.

Comment: Instead of delaying why don't you show a spinner and then display the picker with right values ?

Comment: no i need data as ... depend on picker view option values, data get modify on 2nd textfield.  its like i already have picker view values, but depend on user selection i need to change other values which are there in DB as not fixed. so it so happened my picker view appears 1st before my call to db and i get data.

Comment: How do you fetch your data?

Comment: i simply wanted to delay appears of picker view..... data fetching is normal way iOS...that does not affect .... i had mentioned reason why i want to delay....

Answer (score 2):

You should probably implement the `UITextField` delegate method `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` and return `FALSE` for the text field that needs network data in order to populate the picker. You could display a progress indicator on top of the window as Teja suggested, and then hid the progress "spinner" and call `becomeFirstResponder` on the text field to make it enable editing once the download is complete.

Comment: i already implemented.... all delegates..my code work perfectly fine. i can not return FALSE. or else picker view will never appear. i do not want data for picker view option. picker view data is fixed and i already loading. my problem is only on textFieldShouldBeginEditing delegate, i call DB. at the same time picker view also appears with option. i just want it to delay...so that i will have Data and picker view at the same time....... PLEASE note Data from DB is different. not picker view data. i have two textfields.... one for picker view and another for data depend on 1st textfield.